# Keep receiving abuse messages from my service provider, but cannot find anything in maillog

Tags: email, postfix, spam

I keep receiving from my provider abuse messages, that spam is being sent out from my server, but I cannot find anything in the /var/log/maillog files.  No information is being logged there about these messages. I am suspicious that some PC of one of my customers has a virus and sends out emails, because the abuse messages I receive are rare, every few days....
I have Plesk 12 / Debian installed with protection for Outbound Spam installed. So there is no huge queue in the outgoing mail queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server has been compromised, the intruder may not be using services that log where you can see those logs. If you're getting complaints from your provider about spam being sent from your server, I would take them seriously and assume that the server has indeed been compromised. To anticipate your next question, see [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)